# how to filter records which doesn't have a json key using list Comprehensions python

Tags: python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

I have a Json dictionary where it contains the call information and who handled the call and it contains the call stats under the key "stat".

This dictionary is stored in a variable "interactions"
But in some cases for a given call under a given session there will be no key called "stat".
I am trying to update this json dictionary by removing the handler and the session array if there is no key "stat" and then assign the whole json dict to a new variable.
I have updated the json using the for loop, but its taking long time to perform this operation.
How can i achieve this using list comprehension in python

For example, if you see the below dict, sessionid=abc94 doesn't have a key "stat"

sample input:

interactions =

```
[
  {
    "callId": "17f2e9a7-2c82-4908-80f4-019ec2b8be57",
    "Start": "2023-04-05T16:38:56",
    "handlers": [
      {
        "handlerId": "dafedee8-2869-414f-970e-657f92016e6b",
        "Name": "test",
        "sessions": [
          {
            "ani": "tel:+120134323",
            "direction": "inbound",
            "dnis": "tel:+3243423",
            "requestedRoutings": [
              "Standard"
            ],
            "sessionId": "c7372835-47f3-461c-b506-e604d0633994",
            "stats": [
              {
                "name": "talkcnt",
                "value": 1
              },
              {
                "name": "talktime",
                "value": 903481
              }
            ],
            
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "handlerId": "dafeddfds-2869-414f-970e-657f92016e6b",
        "Name": "test",
        "sessions": [
          {
            "ani": "tel:+120134323",
            "direction": "inbound",
            "dnis": "tel:+3243423",
            "requestedRoutings": [
              "Standard"
            ],
            "sessionId": "cdsfd-47f3-461c-b506-e604d0633994",
            "stats": [
              {
                "name": "talkcnt",
                "value": 100
              },
              {
                "name": "holdtime",
                "value": 232323
              }
            ],
            
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "callId": "23sdf-2c82-4908-80f4-019ec2b8be57",
    "Start": "2023-04-05T16:38:56",
    "handlers": [
      {
        "handlerId": "sdfsdfee8-2869-414f-970e-657f92016e6b",
        "Name": "test",
        "sessions": [
          {
            "ani": "tel:+120134323",
            "direction": "inbound",
            "dnis": "tel:+3243423",
            "requestedRoutings": [
              "Standard"
            ],
            "sessionId": "c7372835-47f3-461c-b506-e6sdfd",
            "stats": [
              {
                "name": "talkcnt",
                "value": 1
              },
              {
                "name": "talktime",
                "value": 903481
              }
            ],
            
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "handlerId": "dafeddfds-2869-414f-970e-657f92016e6b",
        "Name": "test",
        "sessions": [
          {
            "ani": "tel:+120134323",
            "direction": "inbound",
            "dnis": "tel:+3243423",
            "requestedRoutings": [
              "Standard"
            ],
            "sessionId": "abc94"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

expected output:

interactions_updated =

```
[
  {
    "callId": "17f2e9a7-2c82-4908-80f4-019ec2b8be57",
    "Start": "2023-04-05T16:38:56",
    "handlers": [
      {
        "handlerId": "dafedee8-2869-414f-970e-657f92016e6b",
        "Name": "test",
        "sessions": [
          {
            "ani": "tel:+120134323",
            "direction": "inbound",
            "dnis": "tel:+3243423",
            "requestedRoutings": [
              "Standard"
            ],
            "sessionId": "c7372835-47f3-461c-b506-e604d0633994",
            "stats": [
              {
                "name": "talkcnt",
                "value": 1
              },
              {
                "name": "talktime",
                "value": 903481
              }
            ],
            
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "handlerId": "dafeddfds-2869-414f-970e-657f92016e6b",
        "Name": "test",
        "sessions": [
          {
            "ani": "tel:+120134323",
            "direction": "inbound",
            "dnis": "tel:+3243423",
            "requestedRoutings": [
              "Standard"
            ],
            "sessionId": "cdsfd-47f3-461c-b506-e604d0633994",
            "stats": [
              {
                "name": "talkcnt",
                "value": 100
              },
              {
                "name": "holdtime",
                "value": 232323
              }
            ],
            
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "callId": "23sdf-2c82-4908-80f4-019ec2b8be57",
    "Start": "2023-04-05T16:38:56",
    "handlers": [
      {
        "handlerId": "sdfsdfee8-2869-414f-970e-657f92016e6b",
        "Name": "test",
        "sessions": [
          {
            "ani": "tel:+120134323",
            "direction": "inbound",
            "dnis": "tel:+3243423",
            "requestedRoutings": [
              "Standard"
            ],
            "sessionId": "c7372835-47f3-461c-b506-e6sdfd",
            "stats": [
              {
                "name": "talkcnt",
                "value": 1
              },
              {
                "name": "talktime",
                "value": 903481
              }
            ],
            
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
interactions = [
    {
        "callId": "17f2e9a7-2c82-4908-80f4-019ec2b8be57",
        "Start": "2023-04-05T16:38:56",
        "handlers": [
            {
                "handlerId": "dafedee8-2869-414f-970e-657f92016e6b",
                "Name": "test",
                "sessions": [
                    {
                        "ani": "tel:+120134323",
                        "direction": "inbound",
                        "dnis": "tel:+3243423",
                        "requestedRoutings": ["Standard"],
                        "sessionId": "c7372835-47f3-461c-b506-e604d0633994",
                        "stats": [
                            {"name": "talkcnt", "value": 1},
                            {"name": "talktime", "value": 903481},
                        ],
                    }
                ],
            },
            {
                "handlerId": "dafeddfds-2869-414f-970e-657f92016e6b",
                "Name": "test",
                "sessions": [
                    {
                        "ani": "tel:+120134323",
                        "direction": "inbound",
                        "dnis": "tel:+3243423",
                        "requestedRoutings": ["Standard"],
                        "sessionId": "cdsfd-47f3-461c-b506-e604d0633994",
                        "stats": [
                            {"name": "talkcnt", "value": 100},
                            {"name": "holdtime", "value": 232323},
                        ],
                    }
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        "callId": "23sdf-2c82-4908-80f4-019ec2b8be57",
        "Start": "2023-04-05T16:38:56",
        "handlers": [
            {
                "handlerId": "sdfsdfee8-2869-414f-970e-657f92016e6b",
                "Name": "test",
                "sessions": [
                    {
                        "ani": "tel:+120134323",
                        "direction": "inbound",
                        "dnis": "tel:+3243423",
                        "requestedRoutings": ["Standard"],
                        "sessionId": "c7372835-47f3-461c-b506-e6sdfd",
                        "stats": [
                            {"name": "talkcnt", "value": 1},
                            {"name": "talktime", "value": 903481},
                        ],
                    }
                ],
            },
            {
                "handlerId": "dafeddfds-2869-414f-970e-657f92016e6b",
                "Name": "test",
                "sessions": [
                    {
                        "ani": "tel:+120134323",
                        "direction": "inbound",
                        "dnis": "tel:+3243423",
                        "requestedRoutings": ["Standard"],
                        "sessionId": "abc94",
                    }
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
]


def filter_handlers(handlers):
    return [
        {**h, "sessions": sessions}
        for h in handlers
        if (sessions := [s for s in h["sessions"] if "stats" in s])
    ]

interactions_updated = [
    {**i, "handlers": h} for i in interactions if (h := filter_handlers(i["handlers"]))
]

print(interactions_updated)
```

Prints:

```
[
    {
        "callId": "17f2e9a7-2c82-4908-80f4-019ec2b8be57",
        "Start": "2023-04-05T16:38:56",
        "handlers": [
            {
                "handlerId": "dafedee8-2869-414f-970e-657f92016e6b",
                "Name": "test",
                "sessions": [
                    {
                        "ani": "tel:+120134323",
                        "direction": "inbound",
                        "dnis": "tel:+3243423",
                        "requestedRoutings": ["Standard"],
                        "sessionId": "c7372835-47f3-461c-b506-e604d0633994",
                        "stats": [
                            {"name": "talkcnt", "value": 1},
                            {"name": "talktime", "value": 903481},
                        ],
                    }
                ],
            },
            {
                "handlerId": "dafeddfds-2869-414f-970e-657f92016e6b",
                "Name": "test",
                "sessions": [
                    {
                        "ani": "tel:+120134323",
                        "direction": "inbound",
                        "dnis": "tel:+3243423",
                        "requestedRoutings": ["Standard"],
                        "sessionId": "cdsfd-47f3-461c-b506-e604d0633994",
                        "stats": [
                            {"name": "talkcnt", "value": 100},
                            {"name": "holdtime", "value": 232323},
                        ],
                    }
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        "callId": "23sdf-2c82-4908-80f4-019ec2b8be57",
        "Start": "2023-04-05T16:38:56",
        "handlers": [
            {
                "handlerId": "sdfsdfee8-2869-414f-970e-657f92016e6b",
                "Name": "test",
                "sessions": [
                    {
                        "ani": "tel:+120134323",
                        "direction": "inbound",
                        "dnis": "tel:+3243423",
                        "requestedRoutings": ["Standard"],
                        "sessionId": "c7372835-47f3-461c-b506-e6sdfd",
                        "stats": [
                            {"name": "talkcnt", "value": 1},
                            {"name": "talktime", "value": 903481},
                        ],
                    }
                ],
            }
        ],
    },
]
```